# grid operations

Tags: c#

I have a grid populated as in the following structure,

```
       Name           Qualification        Address   
        xx                xx                 xx
        yy                yy                 yy
```

Now I want to make this structure look,

```
       Name           Qualification        Address   
        xx                xx                 xx         Add    Save   Remove   Edit
        yy                yy                 yy         Add    Save   Remove   Edit
```

so that when I click 'Add' button it should add a new row and when Save button is clicked the value in the new row should be saved both in DB and populated in grid.
Likewise when an 'Edit' button is clicked the corresponding row should change to edit mode were the user can make changes and save it clicking the save button.

can anybody help me on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that you're using the ASP.Net GridView element.

If that's the case, this tutorial should help:

http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/GridView_Insert_Edit_Update_Delete.aspx

Good Luck!